# Exception thrown when uploading image ads to AdWords

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, adsense, google-ads-api

I have the following code, whose point is to try to interface with Google AdWords. I want to upload some image ads to Adwords.

```
    var operations = new List<AdGroupAdOperation>();

    foreach (var generatedAd in generatedAds)
    {
        // create a new image to put in the imageAd
        var image = new Image
        {
            data = generatedAd.Image.FileData,
            type = MediaMediaType.IMAGE
        };

        // create a new image ad
        var imageAd = new ImageAd
        {
            image = image,
            name = generatedAd.Image.FileName,
            displayUrl = Config.Get("DisplayURL"),
            url = generatedAd.Ad.Url
        };

        var imageAdGroupAd = new AdGroupAd
        {
            ad = imageAd,
            adGroupId = (long)generatedAd.Ad.AdwordsAdGroupId,

        };

        // prepare to add the new image ad to the ad words group
        var operation = new AdGroupAdOperation
        {
            @operator = Operator.ADD,
            operand = imageAdGroupAd
        };

        operations.Add(operation);
    }

    try
    {
        ((AdGroupAdService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201406.AdGroupAdService))
            .mutate(operations.ToArray());
    }
```

However, running this code results in an exception being thrown. The main exception message is 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.', and the inner exception message is 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'. Have these errors come up before in AdWords? Is there a particular way to handle them?

Can anyone suggest anything at all? I have Googled and come up with some general addvice for these issues but nothing that seems to work for my particular case.

Thanks,
Conor

Comment: Just as a note, on some occasions, the inner exception changes to 'Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.' rather than 'Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'.

No pattern is immediately obvious to explain this.

Comment: I've gotten some unclear errors from images before, and the issue was I was trying to send an invalid image. Can you upload an identical image through the MCC without issue?